# Why does Django ORM add a not specified field in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I want to perform this query with the ORM :

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG("wcm_workflows_transition"."name") AS "names"
FROM "wcm_workflows_transition"
GROUP BY "wcm_workflows_transition"."workflow_id"
ORDER BY "wcm_workflows_transition"."name" ASC;
```

To do this I use

```py
Transition.objects.values("workflow__id").annotate(names=ArrayAgg("name")).values("names")
```

But for some unknown reasons, Django adds `"wcm_workflows_transition"."name"` to the `GROUP BY` clause.
So the query performed by the previous Django ORM expression is :

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG("wcm_workflows_transition"."name") AS "names"
FROM "wcm_workflows_transition"
GROUP BY "wcm_workflows_transition"."workflow_id", "wcm_workflows_transition"."name"
ORDER BY "wcm_workflows_transition"."name" ASC;
```

I cannot use `aggregate` because I want to use the queryset in a subquery.
Here are the models (simplified)

```py
class Workflow:
    name = models.CharField(_(u'Name'), max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)


class Transition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_(u'Name'), max_length=100, db_index=True)
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow, verbose_name=_(u'Workflow'), related_name='transitions',
            db_index=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
```

Now I have two questions :

1. Why Django ORM adds this fields to the `GROUP BY` clause ?
2. How to perform the expected query using the ORM

### What I have tried :

I thought that Django added in the `GROUP BY` all the fields that are used in the annotation, so I changed the field aggregated but it didn't change the grouped by fields.
Then I asked myself if the `name` field had any constraint. In fact it has the `db_index=True` constraint. So I changed the aggrgated field with a not contrained one but `name` was still in the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why Django ORM adds this fields to the `GROUP BY` clause ?

Because the added field is the default `ORDER BY` field.
You can see this in the `Meta` class of the `Transition` model : `ordering = ('name', )`

#### How to perform the expected query using the ORM ?

Add `order_by()` to your query to clear all default ones.
It goes like this :

```py
Transition.objects.order_by().values("workflow__id").annotate(names=ArrayAgg("label")).values("names")
```